# TA-Lib EMA gives inappropriate NaN values

Tags: python, ta-lib

I am using ta-lib for Technical Analysis in Python. Here is a small piece of code I wrote:

```
SBIN=pd.read_csv('SBIN.NS.csv')
ema=TA.SMA(SBIN.Close,timeperiod=20)
```

The first 19 values in the ema array are NaN, which are totally understandable. But after a certain position also, `ema` has NaN values. Why is this happening?

Comment: Could you check your SBIN.Close? May be NaNs are there?

Comment: That was indeed the case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The csv file `SBIN.NS.csv` contains NaN values.`SBIN.dropna(axis=0)` will solve the problem.It will drop all the rows that contains NaN values.

```
SBIN=pd.read_csv('SBIN.NS.csv')
SBIN.dropna(axis=0)
ema=TA.SMA(SBIN.Close,timeperiod=20)
```